# What is my executor being lost due to YARN preemption?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

My Pyspark jobs throw the following error messages:-

`ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 100 on xxx.xxx: Container container_xxx on host: xxx.xxx was preempted`

What does this mean?
How can I prevent it?

Comment: Are you the admin of the cluster?  If so, you can disable preemption.  Do you know if you're running Capacity Scheduler or Fair Scheduler?

Comment: I have no admin rights. I am using a busy cluster with hundreds of users and multiple queues. The queue I am using is 'FairOrderingPolicy'.

Comment: Then you can't prevent this from happening.  The best thing to try is see if you can submit to a higher priority queue.

Comment: I never see this with Tez jobs. Are spark jobs being preempted while Tez jobs aren't or does Tez just not give messages for this?

Comment: Are your spark jobs running longer than your Tez jobs?

Comment: I run lots of different jobs. I have only noticed the preemption message with Spark. It is difficult to say if this is making jobs run for longer.

Comment: Some people run Spark Streaming which means the jobs run a very long time (several days).  If your queues can preempt then it makes sense you'd see the Spark jobs getting killed since they are long running.  If you are running a Tez job and it only takes 5 minutes or less, it's unlikely you'd get preempted during this short er duration.  Does that make sense?